# Eslint allow jsx inside some js files like test component

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I've add eslint with air-bnb configuration to my project, and my project includes test files that test components.Here is my files:

**eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb", "plugin:jest/style"],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "devDependencies": true }]
  }
}
```

**app.test.js**

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

describe('test App component', () => {
  it('expect to render App component', () => {
    expect(shallow(<App />)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

The problem that i have jsx file(component) inside my test which is js extension(test files), for that i encounter this notification `JSX not allowed in files with extension '.js'`
in other words i want to keep this configuration but allow jsx inside test files

Comment: Why not name the tests that contain JSX .jsx too?

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually just i want to keep my project clean(naming)

Comment: What is "unclean" about reflecting in your tests which contain JSX in the same way you do with the code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe for convention; do we consider files import "jsx" is jsx files?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to ask. That file doesn't just *import* JSX, it *contains* it: `shallow(<App />)`.

Comment: Ok, you understand me well, my test files are jsx files, thanks.